# FilteredListMixin (filtering children)

Tags: memory, filter, dojo, store

The below code works when I search for the header attribute (eg. Fruits, Electronics) but it won't work for the children attribute.

From the dojo website (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/FilteredListMixin.html), it said the following.

*"The filtering works for lists backed by a store (dojo/store or dojo/data), as well as for lists not backed by a store. When filtering a list backed by a store containing hierarchical data (data items that are children of a parent data item), the store must support recursive search queries such that the filtering can match child items."*

What does the website means by *"store must support recursive search queries"*, does dojo/store/Memory support *"recursive search queries"*?

Am I missing something here for the children filtering to work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
require([
  "dojo/ready",
  "dojo/_base/declare", 
  "dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList",
  "dojox/mobile/FilteredListMixin",
  "dojo/store/Memory",
  "dojox/mobile/parser",
  "dojox/mobile",
  "dojox/mobile/compat"
], function (ready, declare, EdgeToEdgeStoreList, FilteredListMixin, Memory)
{
  ready(function ()
  {     
    var alldata = [
      {field:"Fruits", label:"Fruits", header: true, children:[{field:"Apple", label:"Apple"}, {field:"Orange", label:"Orange"}]},
      {field:"Electronics", label:"Electronics", header: true, children:[{field:"Hair Dryer", label:"Hair Dryer"}, {field:"Oven", label:"Oven"}]}
    ];

    var param = {};
    param.labelProperty = "label";
    param.idProperty = "field";
    param.constraint = false;
    param.query = {};
    param.stateful = true;
    param.store = new Memory({idProperty:"field", data: alldata});
    param.placeHolder = "Search";
    var ph = new declare([EdgeToEdgeStoreList, FilteredListMixin])(param);
    ph.placeAt("somediv");
    ph.startup();
  });
}
```